# Get the last match of digits between definite strings

Tags: regex, boost

Let I have a string like

```
<sip:73512598312@test.ru>;index=1<sip:73512598313@test.ru;user=phone;cause=302>;index=1.1
```

How can I get 73512598313 from it using boost regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?<=sip:)\d+(?=@test.ru;)`, I guess.